# How to render multiple static files in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, routes

I am trying to use express to render a few different html files from my public folder. These are all static files. I also want to render a 404 page if a route is an invalid route is called. Here is my code.

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
app.use(express.static("public"))


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index")
})

app.get("/about", (req, res) => {
    res.render("about")
})

app.get("/contact-me", (req, res) => {
    res.render("contact-me")
})

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).send("404 for all pages not defined in routes")
})

app.listen(8080)
```

The first route to render index.html works and the 404 status works, but all the other routes give me an error of "No default engine was specified and no extension provided." I tried added an ejs view engine, but the code still doesn't work. All html files are named properly and live in the "public" folder. Any help on this would be amazing! Thanks much!

Comment: `res.render()` only works with templates engines like handlebars, ejs, pug, nunjucks, etc.. which you don't have installed and don't need for static files.  If you just want to send static files, then use the `express.static()` middleware and configure it to point to a directory that contains only public static files.  That middleware will then find and serve those static files automatically.

Comment: Did I use express static correctly in the top instance?

Comment: Using `express.static()` correctly requires alignment of 1) The directory you pass to `express.static()` middleware  2) Location of the files you want to serve in your server file system, 3) The URLs you want to serve those files, 4) The filenames of the static files themselves.  Without knowing all of those, we can't know if you've done it right.  If you had done it right, a URL like `/about` should already work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use handlebars for handling it. To see an example check this [repo](https://github.com/1sh1vam/node-preactice/tree/main/web-server)

Comment: The OP does not show any need for handlebars.  They need to switch to use `express.static()` middleware to serve static files.

Comment: I notice the link is a dead end.

Comment: can you please check it now?